# Discord.js error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')

Tags: javascript, discord.js, typeerror

I have this code to unban someone using id (btw if you know how to unban by "ping" a user that is ban I will like to know how to do that). I have an issue with the id that could be a letter and my code was crashing so I try to fix it but know the problem is that the option are undefined.

Here is my code :

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');
const { SnowflakeUtil } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('unban')
        .setDescription('Send an id of a discord member and unban them.')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('target')
                .setDescription('The id of the member to unban')
                .setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('reason')
                .setDescription('The reason for unbanning'))
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers)
        .setDMPermission(false),

    async execute(client, interaction) {
        const target = interaction.options.get('target');
        if (!target) return interaction.reply({ content: "The 'target' option is missing.", ephemeral: true });

        if (!SnowflakeUtil.deconstruct(target).valid) {
            return interaction.reply({ content: "The target id is not a valid id.", ephemeral: true });
        }

        const reason = interaction.options.get('reason') || 'No reason provided';
        const user = await client.users.fetch(target);
        if (!user) return interaction.reply({ content: "I could not find this user.", ephemeral: true });

        await interaction.reply(`Unbanning ${user.tag} for reason: ${reason}`);
        await interaction.guild.members.unban(user.id);
    },
};
```

The error is :

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')

It is suppose to unban a user of the discord server.

Comment: It means `interaction` is `undefined`. How do you call the `execute` method?

Comment: I agree with Zsolt. You can try flipping the parameters to `async execute(interaction, client)` since most command handler implementations send the interaction first and that may be the issue here

Answer (score -1):

Parameters is probably `execute(interaction, client)`.

This means you need to change parameters in your command to `async execute(interaction, client)`
or you can leave it as it is and write `interaction` where you write `client` and `client` where you write `interaction`. The most appropriate solution would be the first thing I said.